# How to divide the crystal report page horizontally?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, server

I have Records like this...

```
EmpNo      Empname 
 1         Prakash
 2         Ramesh
 3         Vinod
 4         Rajesh
```

I need to display the records in crystal report like this

```
Empno   empName         EmpNo  EmpName
1       Prakash           3     Vinod
2       Ramesh            4     Rajesh
```

Answer (score 0):

In detail section properties (in section expert), check 'Format with multiple columns'. Layout tab appears, there you can set column width.